# Set Mojo parameter from command line (if no property is present)

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

If a Mojo defines a parameter as

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "target/ejbstubs-dep")
private String workdir;
```

is it possible to overwrite this parameter from the command line? Or is it necessary to have `property` attribute in the parameter?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's explained in the documentation : http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Comment: @MickaëlB I already read that page but I could not find the answer to my question.

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: I tried to use `-Dworkingdir=somedir` but it did not work.

Comment: You mean `-Dworkdir=somedir` and not `-Dworkingdir` since the property is `private String workdir`, right ?. Also what did work ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I want to set the value for `workdir` through the command line. If it had a `property` attribute I could use that but it doesn't.

Comment: You need to define `@Parameter( property = "workdir", defaultValue="..")` to make overwriting via command line possible...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done using plugin configuration. You can declare some custom property

```
<configuration>
  <workdir>${ejbstubs.workdir}</workdir>
<configuration>
```

And then it can be configured from the command line.

Comment: Ok, this is a nice idea. It is not really what I wanted, but close.